# Handlerbars template for handling forms

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Currently I create a Handlebars template for each form and use `value={{user}}` in them. So I can fill any form easily for updating any entity. But `select`, `radio` and `ckeckbox`s are different. Is there any clean way to populate these elements too. They do not have `value` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='select'>
  <option selected value=user name=test>test</option>
</select>
```

as you can see, you can control the value of `select` by set "selected" attribute to specific options.

Or you can try embed some javascript code like

```
document.getElementById('select').value={{user}}
```

You need to make sure you have options with correct **value** attributes set

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making use of the `each` helper.

```
<select>
    {{#each options}}
        <option>{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Where options is a plain array (`["apple", "banana", "pear"]`).

You can find more info on the [homepage](http://handlebarsjs.com/). There's also an example where your array contains object, which could be useful should you need to specify `value` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

On stackoverflow, I found this reply : 
[How to set selected select option in Handlebars template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046401/how-to-set-selected-select-option-in-handlebars-template)

With a very good solution (from @janjarfalk edited by @BlaM) :

> With this partial (using Jquery) ...
>
> ```
> window.Handlebars.registerHelper('select', function( value, options ){
>     var $el = $('<select />').html( options.fn(this) );
>     $el.find('[value="' + value + '"]').attr({'selected':'selected'});
>     return $el.html();
> });
> ```
>
> You can wrap selects in your Handlebars template with {{#select status}}...
>
> ```
> <select>
>     {{#select status}}
>     <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
>     <option value="OverDue">OverDue</option>
>     <option value="SentToPayer">SentToPayer</option>
>     <option value="None">None</option>
>     {{/select}}
> </select>
> ```