# Render with handlebars a HTML select element with option selected

Tags: handlebars.js

I render a HTML `select` with Handlebars, but I cannot set the selected value, if such value is itself already a rendered data attribute. I found [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046401/how-to-set-selected-select-option-in-handlebars-template) solutions in SO not satisfactory since they do not address this particular issue.

I tried

```
<select>
    {{#each countriesList}}
    <option value="{{@key}}" {{{isSelected ./setCountry @key}}}>
        {{this}}
    </option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

I have the following `helper` to try to set the selected value

```
isSelected: function (Country, key) {
    return Country === key ? 'selected' : ''; 
}
```

I render in expressjs

```
var countries = {'en': 'England', 'fr': 'France', 'de' : 'Germany'};
var data = {'countriesList':countries, 'setCountry': 'fr'};
res.render('home', data);
```

It should have set the France option as the selected option, but it doesn't work! I also tried to get the rendered attribute from the helper function, but without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently it has to do with the dot. Instead of `./` it should be `../` to make reference to the main data variable. Now it works

```
<select>
    {{#each countriesList}}
    <option value="{{@key}}" {{{isSelected ../setCountry @key}}}>
        {{this}}
    </option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

helper:

```
isSelected: function (Country, key) {
    return Country === key ? 'selected' : ''; 
}
```

expressjs:

```
var countries = {'en': 'England', 'fr': 'France', 'de' : 'Germany'};
var data = {'countriesList':countries, 'setCountry': 'fr'};
res.render('home', data);
```