# Looped RegEx creating second set of elements

Tags: javascript, regex, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars helper that populates select boxes, and I've modified it so it will work with multiple choice select boxes. While it now successfully checks mutiple boxes, it now makes the drop down have two sets of each options.

```
select: function(selected, options){
  let selLength;
  let newOptions;
  if(Array.isArray(selected) == true){
    selLength = selected.length;
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < selLength; i++){
      newOptions += options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp(' value=\"' + selected[i] + '\"'), '$& selected="selected"').replace(new RegExp('>' + selected[i] + '</option>'), ' selected="selected"$&');
    } return newOptions
   } else {
return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp(' value=\"' + selected + '\"'), '$& selected="selected"').replace(new RegExp('>' + selected + '</option>'), ' selected="selected"$&');
  }
},
```

This is being called via:

```
    {{#select userStatus.userGroup}}
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="IT">IT / Development</option>
      <option value="Management">Management</option>
      <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
      <option value="orderFul">Order Fulffilment</option>
      <option value="QA">Quality Analyst</option>
      <option value="Rep">Company Rep</option>
    {{/select}}
```

userGroup is an array containing the groups that the user belongs to.

Comment: What's supposed to arrive at the parameters?

Comment: @Julio Updated post, sorry about that

Comment: @AntonioB: It is unclear what you are trying to do, but it looks like you don't understand how Handlebars' templates or helpers work. Your helper is looping through your `selected` array and, for each item, appending the template block (with some regex replacements) to the output. You are so far off the mark that it is hard to know how to put you on the right track; but I would suggest that you don't need a helper and that, instead, the logic in those regular expressions should go _into your template_.

Comment: @76484 - You are incorrect for a number of reasons. First, most of this code came from "Node.JS/Express/MongoDB from Dev to Deployment", and the code they used comes from this thread: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046401/how-to-set-selected-select-option-in-handlebars-template

Next, I think you are misunderstanding why this is being used. This is a dynamic profile page. The first time it loads there is no data, but after saving if returned to we are simply making sure the information selected previously is show.

Comment: @76484 - Last, my code is simply a modified version of the code provided in the last link, with a modification to try and make it work for multiple select boxes (A select box where multiple options can be selected at once). I tried to be clear I don't understand the regex, but outside of that I think you misunderstand the purpose of the code if you don't see why a helper was used, keeping in mind this is an express application

Comment: @76484 - Here's the full app https://github.com/Abourass/avm_req_desk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do understand what you are trying to do. I have experience with this sort of thing and if you had taken the time to understand what I was advising I think you would have found it helpful.

Your problem is not with the regular expressions. As I noted in my comment, you are appending to your output your entire `#select` block template *for each item in userStatus.userGroup`*.

To clarify: Where in your helper you have `options.fn(this)`, you can think of this as a string containing your template with all of your `<option>` elements. Each time you do `newOptions += options.fn(this)` you are just appending that block to your output; and you are doing this once for *each element* in `selected` which is `userStatus.userGroup`. So if you have 3 elements in `userStatus.userGroup`, you will output your options 3 times:

To fix your helper, you need to stop *appending* to your output  and instead perform all of the replacing on a single string instance.

```
let selLength = selected.length;
let newOptions = options.fn(this);
let i;

for (i = 0; i < selLength; i++) {
    newOptions = newOptions.replace(new RegExp(' value=\"' + selected[i] + '\"'), '$& selected="selected"').replace(new RegExp('>' + selected[i] + '</option>'), ' selected="selected"$&');
}

return newOptions;
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qkdhgs9f/) for reference.

This code will fix your helper, but it is a terrible way to write your application.

The purpose of a template is to produce a string output via data interpolation and conditional control structures. It does not make sense to create a helper that takes your template's output and then performs replacements on that output. The logic of those replacements should be *inside* of your template.

I think a better approach would begin by separating your data from your template. I would advise making the options into data that you supply to your template. For example:

```
options: [
    {
        label: 'IT / Development',
        value: 'IT'
    },
    {
        label: 'Management',
        value: 'Management'
    },
    {
        label: 'Analyst',
        value: 'Analyst'
    },
    {
        label: 'Order Fulfillment',
        value: 'orderFul'
    },
    {
        label: 'Quality Analyst',
        value: 'QA'
    },
    {
        label: 'Company Rep',
        value: 'Rep'
    }
]
```

And your template will become the much simpler and less noisy:

```
{{#each options}}
    <option value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Next, we must figure out how to solve the problem of adding the `selected` attribute to each option whose value can be found in `userStatus.userGroup`. For this we can write a simple helper that will tell us if some value is found in an Array. This use of a helper is legitimate because it is not manipulating our output, but only *helping* with the conditional logic of our template. Here is a simple example of such a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('contains', function (array, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) { return false; }
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
});
```

Now we can use this helper in our template to determine which `<option>` elements should have the `selected` attribute:

```
{{#each options}}
    <option {{#if (contains ../userStatus.userGroup value)}}selected{{/if}} value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/r948Lt6c/) for reference.

I hope you can appreciate why this approach is preferable.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you.
So, if I understand correctly, in order to supply the data to my template I just need to pass it in when setting up the route, correct?

Comment: @AntonioB: Yes.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this concept. Now that I'm making the full version of this app for my work, I want to use this concept, so I've been integrating it in a few places after your advice on better use of templates. My question is, is it more efficient for me to use this method to insert the names / IDs/ link for navigation menu that shows link depending on the users role, or is better to perform the check on the server side when serving the route and serve a different partial depending on role?

Comment: To be more specific, here's my creating the data to fill the #each handlebars helper.
https://github.com/Abourass/AssetVal_Beta/blob/master/modules/roles.js